# wpf - how can I hit test the scrollbars in the scrollviewer?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, hittest

Can someone please tell me how to hit test the scrollbars of a scrollviewer in WPF?

Thanks,

Andy

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Name="myScrollViewer" Width="280" Height="200" MouseMove="ScrollViewer_MouseMove" >


        </ScrollViewer>

        <TextBox Name="myTextBox"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind ...

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            myTextBox.Text = e.GetPosition(myScrollViewer).X + "," + e.GetPosition(myScrollViewer).Y;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx), the MouseEventArgs is relatif to the scrollviewer, so the first parameter is your ScrollViewer.
Then use [PointHitTestParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointhittestparameters.aspx) with the coordinate of the MouseEventArgs.